# SQL BLOB enabled but MDF is still filling up

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Though this involves sharepoint - I think it is more for a SQL question (but someone might prove me wrong)

I've got SQL 2014 Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit) 12.0.2269.0.
I set up FileStream and a BLOB on a content database so I can use it for Sharepoint and get around the 10 gig limitation from SQL Express.

I set it up just like this guide suggests.  https://www.petri.com/install-configure-remote-blob-storage-rbs-sharepoint-farm

Everything looks right, powershell says it's enabled, the tables are there in Sql mgmt studio etc.  When I start migrating data to the sharepoint that uses that Database, the BLOB (the windows folder for that BLOB) grows but the content Database itself also grows at almost the same rate.  So, it appears that SOME data is being stored in the windows folder for the BLOB while SOME data is still being stored in the actual DATABASE to the point where the database filled up.

For full disclosure, I am migrating a sharepoint install with the same (2008) SQL Express BLOB store setup.  That setup shows the content dbase having 1.5Gigs while the blobstore is 90Gigs. Which is what I expected my new setup to do.

I figure I have something set incorrectly within SQL.

I apologize if I am in the wrong place.

Thanks for your help!